# batch file to generate data file with data manipulation

Tags: regex, batch-file

I am not really good in writing batch files, but i have a folder and in this folder several files with specific name convention:

Folder is c:\export_data\
and contains files named 
WE_2153886002_20160307.pdf
WE_2158667003_20170503.pdf

and now i would generate a output file called NC_DOC.DAT in the folder C:\data\

and this should looks like

```
UI;19;0001;2153886002;;;;;;c:\export_data\WE_2153886002_20160307.pdf;WE_2153886002_20160307.pdf;
UI;19;0001;2158667003;;;;;;c:\export_data\WE_2153886002_20160307.pdf;WE_2153886002_20160307.pdf;
```

UI;19;0001 are fixed
2153886002 is the part from the file name
then data folder including the file name
and only the file name.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo off
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B "c:\export_data\WE_*_*.pdf" '
) Do For /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nA"
) Do >>"C:\Data\NC_DOC.DAT" Echo UI;19;0001;%%B;;;;;;%%~fA;%%~nxA
```

- You need one [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to iterate dir output
- another one to parse the filename splitting at the underscore using only the second token.
- use the for var [~ modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to extract the fullname `~f` resp. `~nx` name extension.